# How do I make a variable into a button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button

In my code, I have a variable `<%= phone_number_link(@user.wphone) %>` and I'd like to create a larger clickable button out of it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

you can add a css class to style your element.

```
<%= link_to phone_number_link(@user.wphone), class: "button" %>
```

Comment: that's just creating an anchor like this: href="/user/1?class=button", not creating a link around the variable